# Why will Xcode not update?

Tags: xcode, software-update

Software update always tells me Xcode 6.2 is available.  Other updates install when requested, but when I click the XCode update button it asks me for Apple ID and password.  Other items update without asking.

When I enter those, I never get an error message, and the button dims.  But nothing else ever happens.  Other things will show a progress bar and change the button text to say what is happening.

I accepted the workaround even though it's not exactly an answer to the question as asked.  But it's worth noting here that whatever caused it has been magically corrected.

Comment: Although a "direct download" is a workaround, I'm still puzzled why that item asks for authentication and other large no-cost items do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround, you can download it directly from [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) if you have a (free or paid) account.

**Update:**  At one time the included link above would take one directly to Downloads for Apple Developers after signing in, however as time goes by things change. So once logged into your Developer account add **downloads** to the address in the address bar so it shows as https://developer.apple.com/downloads and then press enter.

You should then be at the Downloads for Apple Developers section as shown in the cropped clip below.

[image]

Comment: The seemingly obvious link to download actually went to a description with an App store button.  For a direct download, use the link for "old versions."  (The current version and the beta of the next are also there.)  My first download had to be killed halfway through after several hours, but the second try was normal.

Comment: Do you delete the old Xcode application after downloading the new version?

Comment: @Angelplayer, In the past I've mostly used the direct download when first installing Xcode and would update through the App Store afterwards however before the App Store, once or twice, I did update manually and deleted the installed Xcode application bundle before starting the install of the newer version.  Because I'm still using OS X 10.8.5 and no longer doing GUI programing I've had no need to upgrade Xcode beyond what I initially installed 3 years ago. Nowadays I mostly just use Command Line Tools for Xcode to manually compile source code of various utilities I use.